# Haskell N00b: IntelliJ giving two errors

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, osx-mavericks

As a junior CS major I'm taking it upon myself to try to cram in learning Haskell over fall breaks (for myself...not sure why I'm torturing myself). I downloaded IntelliJ and installed the official Haskell plugin from Jetbrains.

I'm following instructions from "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!"

While compiling this code:

```
test = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

I get this error:

```
Information:Compilation completed with 2 errors and 1 warning in 2 sec
Information:2 errors
Information:1 warning
Error:cabal: build errors.
Warning:ghc: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    int foo() {}
               ^
/Users/<USER_NAME>/Documents/Dropbox/Developer/IntelliJ/src/Main.hs
    Error:(1, 1) ghc: The function `main' is not defined in module `Main'
```

I don't have this issue when using a text editor and Terminal...however I love IDE's (sorry VIM guys). Also, I'm running OS X 10.9 which, from my research, has been known to cause issues.

Comment: I had a similar problem when running Yesod projects on OS X Mavericks. They disappeared some time ago, I *think* when I wiped my Haskell Platform installation and reinstalled with ghcformacosx.github.io. However, as far as I could tell this warning causes no issues and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `main` function, just like the error tells you. Just have:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

or:

```
test :: IO ()
test = putStrLn "Hello World!"

main :: IO ()
main = test
```

If it's still giving you problems, then at the very beginning of the file just add:

```
module Main where
```

Comment: I tried both versions of the code you gave me (with and without 'module Main where') and now get:    Information:0 errors
Information:1 warning
Warning:ghc: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^

Comment: @user3010203 The warning is probably caused by some borked installation. Just remove Haskell and reinstall it. In any case that's just a warning, it should build just fine.